# How many intersect points does n line have?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

The question is, given n lines by giving x0, y0, x1, y1. Get the number of meeting points. there will be no point that three or more lines intersect. Lines pass (x0, y0), (x1, y1). There will be no same line.
I have an idea is first declare a HashMap, when a new line come, get its slop. If the slop value is not in the HashMap, the result = result + how many lines we have right now. If the slop is in the HashMap, the result = result + (how many lines we have right now - how many lines is with this slop).
Here is my main part of code.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[][] lines = new int[in.nextInt()][4];
    Map<Double, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    int cross = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i< lines.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j< 4; j++)
            lines[i][j] = in.nextInt();
        double slop;
        if(lines[i][2] - lines[i][0] == 0)
            slop = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        else
            slop = (double)(lines[i][3] - lines[i][1]) / (lines[i][2] - lines[i][0]);
        if(!map.containsKey(slop)) {
            cross = cross + i;
            map.put(slop, 1);
        }else{
            cross = cross + (i - map.get(slop));
            map.put(slop, map.get(slop) + 1);
        }
    }
    System.out.print(cross + "\n");
}
```

But the test results shows it is wrong. Could someone help me with which case that I didnt notice or is there anything wrong with my code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: @Zhenbang: Could you edit your question to make it clear that these are not line segments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a nice little problem. Since we are dealing with lines, and we know that the same line doesn't appear twice, and we know that the same intersection point doesn't appear twice, the solution is *almost* as simple as counting one intersection point per pair of lines, i.e. `n * (n-1) / 2`. However, this assumes every pair of lines has an intersection point, which is not true if any lines are parallel; so we need to count how many lines share the same slope, for each slope. It looks like you've figured that out already.

However, it's not clear from your code that you're using those slope counts correctly to calculate the number of intersections. There's some addition and subtraction inside your loop which is hard to reason about. The algorithm is much cleaner if you do it in two separate stages.

If there are `r` lines with the same slope, then the `n * (n-1) / 2` formula assumes they would make `r * (r-1) / 2` intersection points, but since the lines are parallel they actually make 0 intersection points between them. So we need to subtract `r * (r-1) / 2` to correct the count. We need to do this for each slope independently.

So the algorithm can work as follows:

- Build a Map of slopes to counts.
- Initialise a `total` to `n * (n-1) / 2` where `n` is the number of lines.
- For each count `r` in the Map's values, subtract `r * (r-1) / 2` from the total.

Here's an implementation:

```java
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountIntersections {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        long n = in.nextInt();

        Map<Double, Integer> slopeCounts = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int x0 = in.nextInt(), y0 = in.nextInt(),
                x1 = in.nextInt(), y1 = in.nextInt();

            double slope;
            if(x0 == x1) {
                slope = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
            } else {
                slope = (double) (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0);
            }

            slopeCounts.put(slope, slopeCounts.getOrDefault(slope, 0) + 1);
        }

        long total = n * (n-1) / 2;
        for(long r : slopeCounts.values()) {
            total -= r * (r-1) / 2;
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

The variables `n`, `total` and `r` are declared as type `long` instead of `int` so that the multiplication `n * (n-1)` doesn't [overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). This is an issue for values of `n` and/or `r` greater than about 46,000.

Note that there's no problem with calculating the slopes as `double`s here. The numbers being read from the Scanner are `int`s, all of which are exactly representable as `double`s. The subtractions will be exact, and [the IEEE 754 specification guarantees that division of floating point numbers will be correctly rounded](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2017/06/19/sometimes-floating-point-math-is-perfect/). Therefore numerical imprecision will not cause two equal slopes to be calculated slightly differently due to floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Sorry it does make sense. But I tried your method, the judging system still says "incorrect output"

Comment: Please give an example of an input and expected output which this fails on. I'm answering your question, not solving a problem for a judging system I have no relation to. I can only solve the problem within the boundaries of the question as it's asked here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry, that's the key problem. I cannot see what is the failing case.

Comment: Well, the only thing which comes to mind is that if `n` is bigger than 46,000 or so then the formula `n * (n-1) / 2` will overflow and give wrong answers; try replacing the declarations with `long n`, `long total` and `long r`. Otherwise there may be a mismatch between the problem as described in your question here vs. the problem as given by the site you're trying it on. Or there could be some other issue with this code; but "the judging system says incorrect output" isn't useful feedback to me.

Comment: Genius! It does overflow the limit of the integer. Thank you very much and my apologize to the useless comment!

Comment: No worries; if you do these kinds of challenges then you get used to some of the trivial things like that which can cause a "correct" algorithm to give incorrect answers. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

Any pair of non-parallel lines will intersect.

Therefore, the number of intersections is a polynomial function of the number of unique slopes.

The slope of a line is given as `Rise/Run`, but it's dangerous to use this division directly since in floating-point mathematics `4.2/2.2` and `8.4/4.4` may not give the same result. Similarly, subtracting `x0-x1` may introduce floating-point weirdness.

Since it looks as though you are reading the coordinates as integers, consider storing your slopes as `(Rise,Run)` pairs. But notice that `-Rise/Run` and `Rise/-Run` look different; therefore, make a convention that if a slope is negative, that sign should be stored in the `Rise`. Now, simplify your fraction, perhaps by using a [GCD algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor).

Now you have slope in a unique and exact form (much better than what you had before).

Now, proceed as before: if the slope is unique then the number of slopes increases by the number of entries already in your hashset.

Comment: Precision of floating point arithmetic shouldn't be an issue here; the numbers are `int`s, all of which are exactly representable as `double`s, and the IEEE 754 spec actually guarantees correctly-rounded division in the sense that the result will be the floating point number which is closest to the "true" mathematical result. See https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2017/06/19/sometimes-floating-point-math-is-perfect/